# I can not download sample Database for XPages Rich Text Editor Evolution on OpenNTF.org

Tags: xpages

The OpenNTF.org XPages Rich Text Editor Evolution project contains a sample application that evolves the Rich Text Editor control to provide custom inline attachment handling directly within the editor complete with a new embedded image handling user experience with new toolbar actions and dialog experiences.

Unfortunately, the download /release link did not work property :-(

Are there other's link for this sample Database ?

PS.: @Created by Tony McGuckin, Niklas Heidloff

no TAGS for OpenNTF.org-> please tag this Question with it. My reputation not allowed me to create it

Comment: The summary has now been fixed for this project so all the tabs should be working as normal.  Cheers

Comment: +OpenNTF Team, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until the links work you can use this direct link to the release overview of that project (notice the /releases part of the link):

http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Rich%20Text%20Editor%20Evolution/releases/

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem switching tabs on that Project. In the past that's been because of some content on the Summary tab. I've notified the other board members and we'll resolve it as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll wait